# Magento: Exception.log invalid block type

Tags: php, xml, magento

Help! The following is being repeated over in over in my exception.log and i have no idea how to fix it.

```
   2013-09-22T20:08:05+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:   Mage_Enterprise_Cms_Block_Hierarchy_Head' in /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/Mage.php:550
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(469): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(411): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('enterprise_cms/...', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('enterprise_cms/...', 'hierarchy_pagin...')
#3 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('enterprise_cms/...', 'hierarchy_pagin...')
#4 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(110): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '86')
#9 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '86')
#10 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#11 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /chroot/home/artevolu/artevolution.com/html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you!!

Comment: What Magento version are you using ?

Comment: `Enterprise_Cms_Block_Hierarchy_Head` (note there's _no_ `Mage_` in front of that) is a default EE block class. Are you using EE and did override the `<config><global><blocks><enterprise_cms><class>` node? If so, post the override code.